# Unable to configure flutter local notification in app background using plugin flutter_local_notifications

Tags: flutter, notifications, flutter-local-notification

I am trying to configure flutter local notification using the plugin flutter_local_notifications. I follow all those given steps and related to configuration.
However, I cannot get notification sound, color, icon, and other configurations.
All are working once the app is opened status but once it is in the background, it shows notification like a very general using default system notification sound and all with default system setting. Need your assistance to correct it.
here is the code I am using...
**1. main**

```
Future<void> backgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async{
  FlutterAppBadger.updateBadgeCount(1);
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
}

void main()async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(backgroundHandler);
  if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
    AndroidGoogleMapsFlutter.useAndroidViewSurface = true;
  }
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );

  appRunner: () => runApp(const MyApp()),
}
```

2. Home Screen

   ```
     const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
     @override
     State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreen();
   }
   class _HomeScreen extends State<HomeScreen> {
     final Future<FirebaseApp> _initialization =Firebase.initializeApp();
     getIosNotification() async {
       FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
       NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
         alert: true,
         announcement: false,
         badge: true,
         carPlay: false,
         criticalAlert: true,
         provisional: false,
         sound: true,
       );
     }
     @override
     void initState() {
       super.initState();
       _initialization;

       LocalNotificationService.initialize(context);
       getIosNotification();

       FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message) {
          return LocalNotificationService.display(message!);
       });
       FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) {
         return LocalNotificationService.display(message);

       });
       FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((message) {
         return LocalNotificationService.display(message);


       });


     }

     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return const ArtistHomeScreen();
     }

   }


   class PushNotification {
     PushNotification({
       required this.title,
       required this.body,
     });
     String title;
     String body;
   }
   ```
3. Local Notification

   ```
   class LocalNotificationService {
     static final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _notificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

     static void initialize(BuildContext context) {
       final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(android: AndroidInitializationSettings("@mipmap/ic_launcher"));

       _notificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,onSelectNotification: (String? action) async{
         if(action != null){Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(action);}
       });
     }

     static void display(RemoteMessage message) async {
       final Int64List vibrationPattern = Int64List(4);
       try {
         final id = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch~/1000;
         AndroidNotificationDetails notificationDetails =   AndroidNotificationDetails(
                 "test",
                 "testzoy",
                 importance: Importance.max,
                 priority: Priority.high,
                 playSound: true,
                 ticker: 'ticker',
                 sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('notification'),
                 timeoutAfter: 60000,
                 autoCancel: true,
                 enableLights: true,
                 visibility: NotificationVisibility.public,
                 usesChronometer: true,
                 icon: "@mipmap/ic_launcher",
                 largeIcon: const DrawableResourceAndroidBitmap("@mipmap/ic_launcher"),
                 vibrationPattern: vibrationPattern,
                 color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 255, 247),
                 ledColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 255, 247),
                 ledOnMs: 1000,
                 ledOffMs: 500,
                 enableVibration: true,
                 fullScreenIntent: true,
                 // additionalFlags: Int32List.fromList(<int>[4]),
                 colorized: true,
                 channelDescription: 'color background channel description',

         );
         const IOSNotificationDetails iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics =
         IOSNotificationDetails(
             sound: 'notification.aiff',
           presentAlert: true,
           presentBadge: true,
           presentSound: true,
         );
         const MacOSNotificationDetails macOSPlatformChannelSpecifics =MacOSNotificationDetails(sound: 'notification.aiff');
         final LinuxNotificationDetails linuxPlatformChannelSpecifics =
         LinuxNotificationDetails(sound: AssetsLinuxSound('sound/notification.mp3'));
         final NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =
         NotificationDetails(
           android: notificationDetails,
           iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics,
           macOS: macOSPlatformChannelSpecifics,
           linux: linuxPlatformChannelSpecifics,
         );
         await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
           id,
           message.notification?.title,
           message.notification?.body,
           platformChannelSpecifics,
           payload: message.data["payload"],
         );



       } on Exception catch (e) {
         print(e);
       }

     }

   }
   ```